# Ayuda guardar directorio y archivo en array multidimensional

Tags: php, array

Estoy haciendo un código que me permita listar directorios y archivos en un array multidimensional. La idea es utilizar una función opendir y con ella retornar un array con dos dimensiones: `$array [$is_dir] [$is_file]`.
Tengo un código preliminar:

```html
    <body>        
        <?php 
        //función para obtener el nombre de las carpetas y los archivos en array multidimensional
        function dirToArray($dir) { 
            
            //creo un array
            $listDir = array();
            
            //abro los directorios contenidos en $dir
            if($handler = opendir($dir)) { 
                
                //leo todos los elementos contenidos 
                while (false !== ($file = readdir($handler))) { 
                    
                    //verifico que hayan elementos
                    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                        
                        /*si los elementos son archivos, guardo los elementos 
                        en algún indice (dimensión) del array*/
                        if(is_file($dir."/".$file)) { 
                            $listDir[] = $file;
                            
                        /*si los elementos son directorios, guardo los elementos 
                        en otro índice o dimensión, repitiendo hasta que hayan elementos*/
                        }elseif(is_dir($dir."/".$file)){ 
                            $listDir[$file] = dirToArray ($dir."/".$file); 
                        } 
                    } 
                }
                closedir($handler); 
            } 
            return $listDir; 
        } 
       
        ?>
    </body>
```

pero al probarlo me arroja este error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: listDir in C:...

Comment: ¿Qué error te sale exactamente?

Comment: Qué es exactamente lo que le envía por parámetro a su función al llamarla , (su código fue probado y funciona).

Comment: probé la función con:    `$dir = "xxx/";    dirToArray($dir);    echo $listDir[2][1];`

Comment: y aparece el error Notice: Undefined variable: listDir in C:\xxx.php on line 43. (line 43 = `echo $listDir[2][1];`)

Comment: Para poder imprimir en este caso (Un array) usaría `print_r(dirToArray($dir));` , sí en caso encuentre un directorio tendría ue acceder al `print_r(dirToArray($dir)['nombredeldirectorio'][0]);` donde 0 sería el primer file que se encontró en el directorio dentro del directorio a consultar

Comment: Gracias, ahora funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Esta es la forma correcta de iterar sobre el directorio:

```
while (false !== ($entrada = readdir($gestor))) {
    echo "$entrada\n";
}
```

http://php.net/manual/es/function.readdir.php

Comment: Y cual es la diferencia?

Comment: Ambas funcionan. De todos modos corregí el código. Eso sí tengo un problema mostrando un archivo .jpg en el array. Si imprimo ese archivo con `$dir = "xxx/";` y `echo $dir.dirToArray($dir)[1][2];` el código me muestra xxx/xxx.jpg ¿porqué no puedo ver la imagen con `echo '<img src="'.$dir.dirToArray($dir)[1][2].'">';`  ?